# Fetch values from strong parameters in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

How to fetch the value of `dashboard_user` from the params?

```
POST REQUEST:
{
    "dashboard_user": {
        "email": "custom13@example.com",
        "password": "custom",
        "name": "custom13",
        "role_id":7 ,
        "phone": 9999999999,
        "permissions": [1,2,3,11]
    }
}
```

Strong Parameters :

```
params.require(:dashboard_user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :role_id, :phone)
```

Parameters in console:

```
    [1] pry(#<DashboardUsersController>)> params
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"{\n    \"dashboard_user\": {\n        \"email\": \"custom13@example.com\",\n        \"password\": \"custom\",\n        \"name\": \"custom13\",\n        \"role_id\":7 ,\n        \"phone\": 9999999999,\n        \"permissions\": "=>{"1,2,3,11"=>{"\n    }\n}\n    "=>nil}}, "controller"=>"dashboard_users", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>
```

On trying to fetch value:

```
[2] pry(#<DashboardUsersController>)> params[:dashboard_user]
    => nil
```

Comment: How're you making the request? It looks like a whole JSON object there.

Comment: I got the issue , I was sending request of type text from POSTMAN. On changing it to JSON it worked fine.